# Object comparison : Javascript vs Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

Why is there such a difference when comparing 2 objects in Javascript and in Ruby ?
(it is confusing)

in Javascript :

```
obj1 = [1,2];
obj2 = [1,2];

obj1 == obj2 
// false
```

in Ruby :

```
obj1 = [1,2];
obj2 = [1,2];

obj1 == obj2 
# true
```

Comment: Because they're two different languages?

Comment: This is one area where JavaScript and Java are actually similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, arrays are objects, `==` will test if the two objects are the same instance. If you want to compare their contents, read [Comparing two arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/1009479).

---

In Ruby, there are multiple ways to compare objects. `==` is used to compare values, so it makes sense that they are equal.

To compare if they are the same object, use `equal?`:

```
obj1.equal? obj2
# => false
```